# Monotone, periodic 1d-interpolation with continuous 1st order derivative

Tags: interpolation

Lately, we had [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040/187) about interpolation where J. M. linked two interpolation methods. The background for my question is that I estimated a parameter in polar coordinates with dependence on the angle. Therefore, I have a set of values where I know that the values are periodic.

**The question is:** Is there an easy procedure to interpolate a set of (only a few) points so that the interpolant is *monotonic, continuous up to the 1st order derivative, and where the continuous property holds between the start and the end of the interval*?

I tried to tweak `Interpolation`, so if you are interested, please see the following section.

### Example and Investigation

Let's define a simple dataset and use *Mathematica*'s `Interpolation` with `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`:

```
data = {{0, 0.2}, {1/3, 0.9}, {2/3, 0.15}, {1, 0.2}};
ip = Interpolation[data, PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
Show[{
      ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> Full, 
                   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]],
      Plot[ip[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 2]]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does not look so bad at a first glance, but the minimum between the last two points violate the monotonicity (which was expected since the interpolation in *Mathematica* never claimed such a property). Looking at the interpolation graph only and over the interval-boundary shows

```
Plot[ip[x], {x, 0.2, 1.2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that the derivative is not continuous. Now, my idea was that by using `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`, I basically tell *Mathematica* that it can use the values periodically to pad the sides if required. Therefore, a higher interpolation order or maybe using `Method -> "Spline"` *should* be able to make the derivatives continuous. When I try to use

```
Interpolation[data, PeriodicInterpolation -> True, Method -> "Spline"]
```

I get

> Interpolation::mspl: The Spline method could not be used because the data could not be coerced to machine real numbers. >>

which I don't really understand. If I use `InterpolationOrder` and the default `"Hermite"` method, I need a value of 20 to get an *almost* continuous derivative.

Therefore, I tried to do the padding by myself and use `"Spline"` and a low interpolation order (to reduce the overshooting):

```
ip2 = Interpolation[
  Join @@ Table[Plus[{i, 0}, #] & /@ Most[data], {i, 0, 10}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"]

Plot[{ip2[x]}, {x, 5, 6.5}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{5, 0} + # & /@ data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is of course not monotonic, but at least the derivative is continuous:

```
Plot[ip2'[x], {x, 5, 6.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Final solution

I'm accepting the Steffen interpolation in J.M.'s answer as solution for the following reason:

It shows nicely how one can supply derivative values and not only the interpolation values to `Interpolation`. It therefore does not implement a whole new interpolation but it only calculates adjusted derivatives and uses the internal `Interpolation` of *Mathematica*.

Note, that I made some changes in his function. First, the following part

```
pp = Apply[Dot, Transpose[MapAt[Map[Reverse, #] &,
  Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {-1, 1}] &, {h, del}], 1]], 1]/
  ListConvolve[{1, 1}, h, {1, -1}];
```

can be (IMO) slightly simplified to

```
pp = Dot @@@ Transpose[ MapAt[Reverse, 
  Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {-1, 1}] &, {h, del}], {1, All}]]/
  ListConvolve[{1, 1}, h, {1, -1}];
```

which saves a whole pure function and a `Map`. Otherwise, I combined the periodic and the non-periodic interpolation and added a pattern so that data in the form `{y1,y2,...}` can be interpolated in the usual way. (Please change the function name. It's only called like that since I included it in a package)

```
Options[IPCUMonotonicInterpolation] := {
  PeriodicInterpolation -> False
  }

steffenEnds[{{h1_, h2_}, {d1_, d2_}}] := 
 With[{p = d1 + h1 (d1 - d2)/(h1 + h2)}, (Sign[p] + Sign[d1]) Min[
    Abs[p]/2, Abs[d1]]]

IPCUMonotonicInterpolation[data_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), opts___?OptionQ] :=
    IPCUMonotonicInterpolation[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], opts];

IPCUMonotonicInterpolation[data_?MatrixQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{dTrans = Transpose[data], del, h, m, pp, optPeriodic, overhangs},
  optPeriodic = OptionValue[PeriodicInterpolation];
  h = Differences[First[dTrans]]; 
  del = Differences[Last[dTrans]]/h;
  overhangs = If[optPeriodic === False, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}];
  (* Note that overhangs in Partition and ListConvolve are defined differently*)
  pp = Dot @@@ Transpose[MapAt[Reverse, 
    Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, overhangs] &, {h, del}], {1, All}]]/
    ListConvolve[{1, 1}, h, -1*overhangs];
  If[optPeriodic === True,
   del = ArrayPad[del, 1, "Periodic"]
   ];
  m = ListConvolve[{1, 1}, 2 UnitStep[del] - 1] *
                MapThread[Min, {Partition[Abs[del], 2, 1], Abs[pp]/2}];
  Interpolation[
   {{#1}, ##2} & @@@ Transpose[Append[dTrans,
      If[optPeriodic === True,
       m,
       Flatten[{
         steffenEnds[#[[{1, 2}]] & /@ {h, del}],
         m,
         steffenEnds[#[[{-1, -2}]] & /@ {h, del}]
         }]
       ]
      ]],
   PeriodicInterpolation -> optPeriodic]
  ]
```

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5929

Comment: Your simplification yields somewhat different results from the usual Steffen formula. Witness the difference between `Apply[Dot, Transpose[MapAt[Map[Reverse, #] &, Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {-1, 1}] &, {Table[Subscript[h, k], {k, 5}], Table[Subscript[Δ, k], {k, 5}]}], 1]], 1]` and `Dot @@@ Transpose[Map[Partition[Reverse[#], 2, 1, {-1, 1}] &, {Table[Subscript[h, k], {k, 5}], Table[Subscript[Δ, k], {k, 5}]}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. This is hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, halirutan and me already discussed this topic in the chat room only a few days ago, but he thought there should be an explicit question and answer here on main. So, here's my take...

The key here is that the [Fritsch-Carlson](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717021) (the algorithm behind MATLAB's [`pchip()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html)) and [Steffen](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990A%26A...239..443S) interpolation methods are both very easily modified to account for periodic data; one only needs to get rid of the special handling of the endpoints, and pad the data accordingly. (A similar treatment can be done for Stineman interpolation, as presented in PlatoManiac's answer, of course.)

Here's the *Mathematica* implementation for these two $C^1$ interpolation methods:

```
FritschCarlsonPeriodicInterpolation[data_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{dTrans = Transpose[data], del, h, m},
        h = Differences[First[dTrans]]; del = Differences[Last[dTrans]]/h;
        m = If[Equal @@ Sign[Last[#]] && And @@ Thread[Last[#] != 0], 
               3 Total[First[#]]/Total[({{1, 2}, {2, 1}}.First[#])/Last[#]], 0] & /@
            Transpose[{Partition[h, 2, 1, {-1, 1}], Partition[del, 2, 1, {-1, 1}]}];
        Interpolation[MapThread[Append[MapAt[List, #1, 1], #2] &, {data, m}], 
                      PeriodicInterpolation -> True]]

SteffenPeriodicInterpolation[data_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{dTrans = Transpose[data], del, h, m, pp},
        h = Differences[First[dTrans]]; del = Differences[Last[dTrans]]/h;
        pp = MapThread[Reverse[#1].#2 &, Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {-1, 1}] &, {h, del}]]/
             ListConvolve[{1, 1}, h, {1, -1}];
        del = ArrayPad[del, 1, "Periodic"];
        m = ListConvolve[{1, 1}, 2 UnitStep[del] - 1] *
            MapThread[Min, {Partition[Abs[del], 2, 1], Abs[pp]/2}];
        Interpolation[MapThread[Append[MapAt[List, #1, 1], #2] &, {data, m}], 
                      PeriodicInterpolation -> True]]
```

(Contrast these routines with the implementation of vanilla Fritsch-Carlson [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11859) and vanilla Steffen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040).)

As an example:

```
data = {{0, 0.2}, {1/3, 0.9}, {2/3, 0.15}, {1, 0.2}};

ip = Interpolation[data, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
fcp = FritschCarlsonPeriodicInterpolation[data];
sp = SteffenPeriodicInterpolation[data];

Plot[{ip[t], fcp[t], sp[t]}, {t, -1, 2}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Red], Point[data]}]
```

[image: shape-preserving periodic interpolants]

The Steffen and Fritsch-Carlson periodic interpolants are nigh-indistinguishable, but do a better job of preserving the shape of the data than the default periodic interpolation method.

Answer (score 14):

One can look at the paper [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0717021). However, from the [Wolfram Library Archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/1933/), I got this ready-made code that needed only the `CompilationTarget -> "C"` part to modernize:

```
StinemanInterpolatingFunction::dmval=
"Input value lies outside domain of the interpolating function.";
Format[StinemanInterpolatingFunction[range_,_]]:=
SequenceForm["StinemanInterpolatingFunction[",range,", <>]"];
lin=Compile[{x0,y0,x1,y1,x},(y0(x1-x)+y1(x-x0))/(x1-x0),
CompilationTarget-> "C"];
delta=Compile[{x0,y0,y0p,x,linint},(y0+y0p (x-x0)-linint),
CompilationTarget-> "C"];
sC=Compile[{x0,x1,x,linint,delta0,delta1},
linint+delta0*delta1*
If[delta0*delta1>0,
1/(delta0+delta1),
If[delta0*delta1==0,
    0,
    (2x-x0-x1)/((delta0-delta1)(x1-x0))
    ]
    ],
CompilationTarget-> "C"];
home[{_,_},_]:=1;
home[xvals_,x_]:=Module[{n=Length[xvals],h},
h=Quotient[n,2];
Which[x<xvals[[h]],
home[Take[xvals,h],x],x>xvals[[h+1]],h+home[Take[xvals,h-n],x],True,h]
];
endslope[{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_},s2_]:=Module[{z=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)},
z+If[!Negative[z (z-s2)],
z-s2,
1/(1/(z-s2)+Sign[z-s2]/Abs[z])]
];
augment[data_]:=Module[{temp1,temp2,dTrans,yji,ykj,xji,xkj,midslopes},
dTrans=Transpose[data];
{xji,yji}=Rest[Drop[#,-1]]-Drop[#,-2]&/@dTrans;
{xkj,ykj}=Drop[#,2]-Rest[Drop[#,-1]]&/@dTrans;
{temp1,temp2}={xkj^2+ykj^2,xji^2+yji^2};
midslopes=(yji temp1+ykj temp2)/(xji temp1+xkj temp2);
Transpose[{data,Join[{endslope[First[data],data[[2]],First[midslopes]]},midslopes,
                {endslope[Last[data],data[[-2]],Last[midslopes]]}]}]
];
StinemanInterpolation[data_]:=
StinemanInterpolatingFunction[data[[{1,-1},1]],augment[N[data]]];
StinemanInterpolatingFunction[{r_,s_},data_][x_?NumberQ]:=
Message[StinemanInterpolatingFunction::dmval]/;!(r<=x<=s);
StinemanInterpolatingFunction[{r_,s_},adata_][x_?NumberQ]:=
Module[{d,linearInt},
d=Flatten[{adata[[home[First/@First[Transpose[adata]],x]+{0,1}]],x}];
Apply[sC,Join[d[[{1,4,7}]],
     {linearInt=lin@@d[[{1,2,4,5,7}]],
     delta@@Join[d[[{1,2,3}]],{x,linearInt}],delta@@Join[d[[{4,5,6}]],
     {x,linearInt}]}]]
];
```

Now this seems to work well:

```
data = {{0, 0.2}, {1/3, 0.9}, {2/3, 0.15}, {1, 0.2}};
ip = Interpolation[data, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
f1 = StinemanInterpolation[data];
Show[{Plot[Evaluate[{ip[x], f1[x]}], {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, {Thick, Cyan}}], 
     ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
     PlotRange -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.025]]]}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot of interpolant]

The padded data also works as expected:

```
ip2=Interpolation[Join@@Table[Plus[{i,0},#]&/@Most[data],{i,0,10}],
      InterpolationOrder->2,Method->"Spline"];
f2=StinemanInterpolation[Join@@Table[Plus[{i,0},#]&/@Most[data],{i,0,10}]];
Plot[{ip2[x],f2[x]},{x,5,6.5},
   Epilog->{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[{5,0}+#&/@data]},
   Frame-> True,Axes-> False,PlotRange-> All]
```

[image: plot of interpolant of padded data]

BR

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It looks like the JSTOR paper you are linking to discusses 2D interpolation. Did you mean some other reference?

Comment: Wikipedia provides more relevant references in the article on [monotone cubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation).

Comment: @Sasha, yes, the method in that paper Plato linked to is for bivariate interpolation. Probably he intended to link to [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717021) (and I gave implementations [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11859)).

Comment: Nice one (+1)...

Comment: @hal, the Stineman scheme can certainly be readapted for periodic data (e.g. remove the `endslope[]` bits, as well as modifying the interval bisection routine `home[]`)...

Comment: @J.M. You are right I gave the wrong reference in hurry as I had a bus to catch ;)

Comment: @Sasha the wiki info is quite useful. Did not have time to explore it through implementation.

Comment: Thx! @b.gatessucks edited..

Answer (score 9):

Being rather dissatisfied with the implementation of [Stineman interpolation](http://www.sendspace.com/file/cq382f) presented here (among other things, the computation of `endslope[]` is superfluous, as previously noted), I decided to roll out my own implementation of periodized Stineman interpolation. Here it is:

```
StinemanPeriodicSlopes[data_?MatrixQ] := With[{sq = {#2.#2, #1.#1}},
        {#1[[2]], #2[[2]]}.sq/{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}.sq] & @@@
        Partition[Differences[data], 2, 1, {-1, 1}]

StinemanPeriodicInterpolation::inddp = "The point `1` is duplicated.";

StinemanPeriodicInterpolation[data_] := Module[{diffs, times},
  StinemanInterpolatingFunction[data[[{1, -1}, 1]], 
          Append[Transpose[data], StinemanPeriodicSlopes[data]], True] /; 
          If[MemberQ[diffs = Chop[Differences[times = data[[All, 1]]]], 0], 
             Message[StinemanPeriodicInterpolation::inddp, 
                     First[Extract[times, Position[diffs, 0]]]]; False, True]]

StinemanInterpolatingFunction::dmval =
     "Input value `1` lies outside the domain of the interpolating function.";

Format[StinemanInterpolatingFunction[range_, __]] := 
       SequenceForm["StinemanInterpolatingFunction[", range, ", <>]"]

StinemanInterpolatingFunction[{p_, q_}, data_, False][x_?NumericQ] :=
     (Message[StinemanInterpolatingFunction::dmval, x]; $Failed) /; ! (p <= x <= q)

StinemanInterpolatingFunction[{p_, q_}, data_, perQ_][x_?NumericQ] := 
     Module[{dl, dp, dr, h, l, li, m, r, t, tl, tr, xa, ya, yp},
            {xa, ya, yp} = data;

            t = If[perQ, Mod[x, q - p, p], x];

            l = 1; r = Length[xa];
            While[r - l > 1,
                  m = Quotient[l + r, 2];
                  If[t < xa[[m]], r = m, l = m]];

            tl = t - xa[[l]]; tr = t - xa[[r]]; h = xa[[r]] - xa[[l]];
            li = {-ya[[l]], ya[[r]]}.{tr, tl}/h;
            dl = ya[[l]] + yp[[l]] tl - li; dr = ya[[r]] + yp[[r]] tr - li;
            dp = dl dr;
            li + dp Switch[Sign[dp], 1, 1/(dl + dr), 0, 0, -1, (tl + tr)/(h (dl - dr))]]
```

For comparison purposes, here's how to use Stineman's slope formula with Hermite interpolation:

```
StinemanHermitePeriodicInterpolation[data_] := Interpolation[
  MapThread[Append[MapAt[List, #1, 1], #2] &,
            {data, StinemanPeriodicSlopes[data]}], PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
```

Here's OP's data set, again:

```
data = {{0, 0.2}, {1/3, 0.9}, {2/3, 0.15}, {1, 0.2}};
```

Here's two periodic interpolants:

```
st = StinemanPeriodicInterpolation[data];
sh = StinemanHermitePeriodicInterpolation[data];
```

Plot 'em:

```
Plot[{st[t], sh[t]}, {t, -1, 2}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Red], Point[data]}]
```

[image: periodized Stineman interpolants]

I've already made provisions for the possibility of combining the periodic and nonperiodic versions of Stineman interpolation, but I'll leave the actual implementation as an exercise for the involved reader.