# Random particle motion

Tags: graphics, random

I have a foundational function that allows me to simulate particles moving in a box according to some movement function. The code is here:

```
obj[{xfunc_, yfunc_}, rad_, lag_, npts_][x_] := 
 MapThread[{Opacity[#1, ColorData["SunsetColors", #1]], 
    Disk[{xfunc@#2, yfunc@#2}, rad Exp[#1 - 1]]} &, 
  Through[{Rescale, Identity}[Range[x - lag, x, lag/npts]]]]

frames = Most@
   Table[Overlay[
     Table[Graphics[
        obj[{Sin[2 #] + RandomReal[] &, Sin[3 #] &}, 0.1, 1, 500][u], 
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> False, 
        ImageSize -> 300, Background -> Black]~Blur~3, {particlenumber, 1, 
       2}]], {u, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
```

Currently, I have `Sin[2 #]+RandomReal[]` and `Sin[3#]` as movement functions, and this works fine.

[image]

However, I would like to have a random particle motion.

**Question:** How can I replace my current movement functions with ones that will generate random, continuous motion for my particles?

Comment: I believe with some graphical sugar, your question would definitely receive more attention. I took to liberty to slightly change your post :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are endless possibilities to model random movement. Let me show an easy one that fits into your current code. You have two functions `xfunc` and `yfunc` that define the movement of your particle. Currently, you are using a combination of two sine's which gives something similar to a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).

What you could do instead, is to use random points. So instead of a smooth sine-curve for the x- and y-movement, you use a set of random points and interpolate between them. The curve for the e.g. x-movement could then look like this

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are some things to consider: For a nice loop, you probably want your interpolation to be periodic so that you end where you start. A linear interpolation like the above gives you hard turns in your particles. For a smoother version you can e.g. use one of the two monotonic, periodic interpolations that @J.M. described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14705/187).

Let me use the `FritschCarlson` method here

```
FritschCarlsonPeriodicInterpolation[data_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{dTrans = Transpose[data], del, h, m}, 
  h = Differences[First[dTrans]]; del = Differences[Last[dTrans]]/h;
  m = If[Equal @@ Sign[Last[#]] && And @@ Thread[Last[#] != 0], 
      3 Total[First[#]]/Total[({{1, 2}, {2, 1}}.First[#])/Last[#]], 
      0] & /@ Transpose[{Partition[h, 2, 1, {-1, 1}], 
      Partition[del, 2, 1, {-1, 1}]}];
  Interpolation[
   MapThread[Append[MapAt[List, #1, 1], #2] &, {data, m}], 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True]]
```

To create a random periodic function with the above function, we create a table of `n` points (we pay attention, that the first point is also the last point).

```
makeRandomFunc[{t0_, t1_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, n_] := 
 With[{dt = (t1 - t0)/(n - 1)},
  FritschCarlsonPeriodicInterpolation[
   Append[#, {t1, #[[1, 2]]}] &@
    Table[{t, RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}]}, {t, N@t0, t1 - dt, dt}]]
  ]
```

Now, we can create new movement functions, that don't leave your box of `{-2,2}`. I'm using `t` from -1 to 0 to fit in what you already have

```
{xfunc, yfunc} = Table[makeRandomFunc[{-1, 0}, {-2, 2}, 20], 2]
```

The rest is basically your code. I just removed some parts and rasterized the graphics which usually gives better performance when you view the animation

```
obj[{xfunc_, yfunc_}, rad_, lag_, npts_][x_] := 
 MapThread[{Opacity[#1, ColorData["SunsetColors", #1]], 
    Disk[{xfunc@#2, yfunc@#2}, rad Exp[#1 - 1]]} &, 
  Through[{Rescale, Identity}[Range[x - lag, x, lag/npts]]]]

frames = Most@
   Table[Rasterize@
      Graphics[obj[{xfunc, yfunc}, 0.1, .1, 500][u], 
       PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> False, 
       ImageSize -> 300, Background -> Black]~Blur~3, {u, 0, 1, 
     0.01}];
```

[image]