# How to (correctly) interpolate an array of points?

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to obtain an interpolation function for points of an x^(-5) function (which goes to infinity at x = 0).

```
hyper = Flatten[Table[[x^(-5)], {x, 1, 100}]];
points = Range[100];

data =  Transpose@{points, hyper}
```

If I do a ListPlot of *data*, I have:

[image: List Plot of the x^(-5) function]

If I use interpolation like:

```
Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline"]
Interpolation[data, Method -> "Hermite"]
```

I get an interpolating function with this form:

[image: Interpolating function with the ListPlot points]

Clearly, the interpolation function has not the simplest form for 'joining' those points, since it has an uprising between x = 3 and x = 4, and an oscillatory behavior.

**My question is: Can I make some kind of interpolation to *data* which reproduces the form of the true function, without those oscillations?**

In particular, I'm interested in get an appropriate value of the interpolating function at x = 3.68, for example.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You may profit from using a lower interpolation order: try e.g. `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2]`.

Comment: And also you have to decide if you want interpolation or fit.

Comment: If you are interested in more rigorously monotonic interpolation, which is difficult if not impossible to achieve with data varying over such a large range of values, see also: [Fritsch-Carlson monotonic cubic interpolation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11859/27951), [Steffen interpolation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040/27951).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the data are very unlike a polynomial, thus ill-suited for polynomial interpolation. On the other hand, the inverse data represent a polynomial, so interpolate them:

```
invdata = Transpose@{points, 1/hyper};
invinterp = Interpolation[invdata]
Plot[1/invinterp[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

In general, the art of polynomial approximation and interpolation involves invertable transformations that put your functions into something whose trajectory resembles a polynomial.

Comment: Good observation. Works much smoother using the inverse

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

If the function's derivative is easy to obtain, then the default piecewise interpolation works fairly well when the derivative values are specified.
One can also use [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html).
With `FunctionInterpolation` you can adjust the options to achieve a desired accuracy.

```
f = x^-5;
df = D[f, x];
data = Table[{{x}, f, df}, {x, 1., 100.}];
ifn1 = Interpolation[data];

ifn2 = FunctionInterpolation[x^(-5), {x, 1., 100.}]; (* complains... *)
```

> FunctionInterpolation::ncvb: FunctionInterpolation failed to meet the prescribed accuracy and precision goals after 6 recursive bisections near x = {1.}. Continuing to refine elsewhere. >>

```
ifn3 = FunctionInterpolation[x^(-5), {x, 1., 100.},               (* use options to fix *)
   MaxRecursion -> 16, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 14];  (* as desired *)
```

Comparison of error of the three methods:

```
Plot[x^(-5) - {ifn1[x], ifn2[x], ifn3[x]} // RealExponent // Evaluate,
 {x, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"ifn1", "ifn2", "ifn3"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, that was an interesting answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just sample your function on a finer grid.  Using grid spacing of 1, like you are, leads to horrible interpolation, whereas a grid spacing of 0.1 works out perfectly.

```
(data = Table[{x, x^-5}, {x, 1, 100, #}];
   Show[
    Plot[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3][x], {x, 1, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400], ListPlot[data], 
    PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, All}
    ]
   ) & /@ {1, .5, .1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a function like this though, it is actually better to sample on a finer grid in a region where the value changes quickly, and on a sparser grid where it changes slowly.  You can look at the grid that [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) comes up with after its recursions:

```
fn = FunctionInterpolation[x^-5, {x, 1, 100}];
fn[[3]]
ListPlot@%
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]