# InterpolationOrder creates a sharp valley even if I increase the number of points. How to have a smooth curve?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have a set of data as the following

```
data = {{-(1/10), 0.1231238244553477`}, {0, 0.11842669584606009}, {1/
   10, 0.11295156506691292`}, {1/5, 0.10626995173555345`}, {1/4, 
   0.10225817762630054`}, {27/100, 0.10051846336254686`}, {7/25, 
   0.09963726811580004`}, {29/100, 0.09877358379658636`}, {3/10, 
   0.0979774456159904`}, {63/200, 0.09726355431994167`}, {8/25, 
   0.0974294913135746`}, {13/40, 0.09826117039951159`}, {1/3, 
   0.1265770484367747`}}
```

ListPloting the data

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> None, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 13, RotateLabel -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 PlotRange -> {5/100, 15/100}, Joined -> True, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

leads to the following plot

[image]

While keeping the interpolationOrder, I want to have a smooth graph without a sharp valley, something like the red curve in the following plot

[image]

What should I do?

p.s., Increasing the number of points didn't solve the problem.

I saw a similar plot in a paper:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, hunting for a method that makes your data look nicer than standard methods looks suspicious, speaking as someone from outside science.

That said, here's a standard method, Eugene Lee's "centripetal" parametrization.  See [this answer by @J.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10277/4999) for more, including a reference.

```
parametrizeCurve[pts_List, a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] := 
  FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]] /;
    MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ];

tvals = parametrizeCurve[data, 0.6]; (* a = 0.6 *)
plot = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[Interpolation[Transpose@{tvals, data}, t]],
  {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.61, Frame -> True] (*//
 Show[#,
   Graphics[{First@
      Cases[Cases[#, {___, _Line, ___}, Infinity], _Directive, 
       Infinity],
     PointSize@Medium, Point@data}]
   ] &*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Uncomment the `Show[..]` code to see the data points marked.

Note that Lee's method is a standard in computer design, not data analysis AFAIK.  But it makes a pretty curve, if that is important.  Searching for the value `0.6` for the parameter `a` is still a bit like $P$-hunting.  While `0.7` looks a little nicer, the following shows whether the plot is the graph of a function (shows whether the horizontal coordinate steadily increases):

```
Cases[Normal@plot, _Line, Infinity][[1, 1, All, 1]] // 
  Differences // Min // Positive
(* True (a=0.6), False (a=0.7) *)
```

---

*Update: Hacking `Interpolation`*

If you want to be sure you have a function, you can adjust the derivatives at the interpolation nodes "by eye" to get a good looking plot:

```
ddata = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[
   1,                        (* first derivative *)
   data[[All, 1]],           (* grid ("x" values) *)
   data[[All, 2]],           (* function values *)
   "DifferenceOrder" -> 2];  (* central diff. rule *)
ddata = ReplacePart[         (* adjust f' by hand *)
   ddata, {-2 :> 0.3, -3 :> 0.08}]; 
ip = Interpolation[
   Transpose@{List /@ data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], ddata}];
Plot[ip[x],
 {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, you have to hunt for `a=0.3` and `b=0.08`. (Using `Manipulate[]` is easiest.)

Answer (score 7):

You are creating the "valley" yourself by using polynomial interpolation. Polynomials always overshoot if the slope changes rapidly.

What to do? You can ask yourself if high degree interpolation is really necessary, because the data is rather smooth:

ListLinePlot[data]

[image]

If you insists on interpolation by some curve, you may try Interpolation together with a spline method and InterpolationOrder->1. With this  you get:

```
f = Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[f[x], {x, -0.10, .4}, PlotRange -> {0.09, .15}]
```

[image]

However, even if you increase the interpolation order by only, 1 you get some artefacts:

f = Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot[f[x], {x, -0.10, .4}, PlotRange -> {0.09, .15}]

[image]

Comment: @Huber Thank you very much for the answer. Since there are some breaks in the graph (when using ListLinePlot) and as I want to have a smooth graph, I used Interpolation. By using  Method -> "Spline",  there still is a break in the plot. Is it possible to have a smother curve?

Comment: Where do you see a break in the plot? I see a continuous line.

Comment: I think the OP means that `f'[x]` is discontinuous (makes "corners" or "kinks" in the graph -- a break in smoothness) for order 1. Of course order 2 has a continuous derivative  but makes the wiggle near 3.2, which you have already observed.

Comment: @Huber at the vicinity of 0.3 there are small breaks

Comment: I don't think there's any difference (except the points generated) in the plots of `ListLinePlot`, `Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 1]`, or even `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` -- they all connect the data points with straight lines.

Answer (score 7):

**modified**

Try `Method -> "Hermite"`

```
ip = Interpolation[data, Method -> "Hermite", InterpolationOrder -> 2 ];
Show[{Plot[ip[x], {x, -.1, .4}, PlotRange -> {0.09, .15}],ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Inspired from @MichaelE2' comments here I show two alternatives
`ResourceFuncion["MonotonicInterpolation"]` and [pchip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/%ce%97ow-to-create-an-interpolated-cdf-from-its-samples/11859#11859) ( thanks to @J. M.'s lack of A.I. )

monotonic interpolation

```
Plot[ResourceFunction["CubicMonotonicInterpolation"][data][
  x], {x, .3, .35}, Axes -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}, Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {.05, .15}]
```

[image]

pchip

```
fcint[data_] := 
 Module[{del, slopes, tau}, del = #2/#1 & @@@ Differences[data];
  slopes = Flatten[{del[[1]], MovingAverage[del, 2], del[[-1]]}];
  tau = MapThread[Min, 
    Through[{Append, Prepend}[
      Min[#, 1] & /@ (3 del/(Norm /@ Partition[slopes, 2, 1])), 1]]];
  Interpolation[
   Transpose[{List /@ data[[All, 1]], data[[All, -1]], slopes tau}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Hermite"]]

 Plot[fcint[data][x], {x, .3, .35}, Axes -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}, Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {0, .15}]
```

[image]

Both alternatives avoid valleys!  Perhaps `monotonic interpolation` gives better extrapolation ...

Whether the additional effort of the two last variants is worthwhile compared with the first approach `Hermite/InterpolationOrder->2` seems doubtful

Comment: `"Hermite"` is the default method. The principal difference here is `Interpolation -> 2` instead of `3`. Also the large points raise the question whether there are kinks being hidden.

Comment: The "Hermite" method works better for the purpose I have. Interpolation->2 or 3 besides the "Hermite" method gives the same result, i.e., a smooth curve with no breaks and vallies.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! Some years ago we were talking about `pchip` and `monotone interpolation`. Unforunately I couldn't find the link...

Comment: I probably can't find it either (I've made over 15K comments). I may have been wrong: At some point, I was told Mma's Hermite and Matlab's `pchip` used the same algorithm. This turns out to be wrong. `pchip` adjusts the slopes at the data points to preserve monotonicity (there is an algorithm given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation), based on the same reference given for [`pchip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html)). Sorry, if I was in error before.

Comment: There is [a resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonotonicInterpolation/) for `"MonotonicInterpolation"`, and it produces an interpolant that is monotonic over intervals in which the data is monotonic. It's wiggles a bit at the sharp turn, though. It cites a different paper than the one for `pchip` (and uses quadratic optimization), so it's almost certainly a different algorithm and gives a different result. I didn't like the result, but maybe there's a way to get it to work well.

Comment: Google turned this up (first try, top hit, haha): This is a relevant comment below our discussion by @J.M., who implement the Fritsch-Carlson algorithm for `pchip`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161633/hermite-interpolation#comment446294_161635 -- and I just found this resource function for it by J.M.: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicMonotonicInterpolation/ Maybe you could see if using the `pchip` approach (your idea) works well here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for your several effords. I'll try to realize my approach the next days

Comment: @MichaelE2 I added two alternatives to my answer

Comment: The monotonic interpolation is beautiful. It's nice to have an algorithm that does better the hack I tried by hand. The `fcint[]` looks too wiggly between `-0.1` and `0.3`, although it's good between `0.3` and `1/3`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Trying to verify `Interpolation[data, Method -> "Hermite", InterpolationOrder -> 2 ]` I cannot reproduce the slopes which Mathematica uses. Any idea how to get the correct formulas? I tried symbolically quadratic interpolation of three points and `NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1,data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], "DifferenceOrder" -> 2] ` without succes. Thanks!

Comment: I believe `Interpolation` computes the order-2 interpolant for $[x_{i-1},x_i)$ from $(x,y)$ data using the three points at $x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1}$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n-1$ and for $[x_{n-1},x_n]$ the the three points $x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n$. Examine `InterpolationToPiecewise[
 Interpolation[data, Method -> "Hermite", InterpolationOrder -> 2], x]` with `InterpolationToPiecewise[]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753). The interpolant (in the case of `data`) is stored in the form of Newton divided differences, which are the coefficients multiplying the $(x-x_i)$ in the output.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks!  I expected the derivative at xi (inner point) follows from the quadratic interpolant `q2'[xi]` but it isn't equal to ` Interpolation[data, Method -> "Hermite", InterpolationOrder -> 2]'[xi]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You're right. The `if'[xi]` is computed from the interpolant based on $x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1}$. It seems that `x < First@#` should be changed to `x <= First@#` in the code for `InterpolationToPiecewise[]`.